# Angular nested object binding not working inside button onclick

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular11

```
<button (click)=updateDetails(app.id, app.extension.applicationId)>
      click this button
</button>
<br/>
<span>{{ app.extension.applicationId }}</span>
```

If I remove the HTML button element from my angular component code, the application seems to be correctly printing the value of the app.extension.applicationId. But if I add the HTML button element code then I see the below error during compilation,

> Argument of type 'extension' is not assignable to the parameter of
> type 'string'

I am using nested objects in my application view.

More details below

The Rest service response that I am consuming

```
{
  "id": 86,
  "parentId": 65,
  "parentApplication": "Digital Tools",
  "extension": {
    "applicationId": 89,
    "applicationName": "ChatBot",
    "applicationRegion": "NA",
  }
}
```

updateDetails method signature

```
updateDetails(id: number, applicationId: string)
```

interfaces I have created

```
interface Extension {
    applicationId: string;
    applicationName: string;
    applicationRegion: string;
}

export interface Application {
    id: number;
    parentId: string;
    parentApplication: string;
    extension: {
        [key: string]: Extension;
    };
}
```

The application prints all the JSON response property values correctly and only the property app.extension.applicationId when used inside the Angular click function throws an error.
But if I were to pass app.parentApplication as the argument the function seems to be compiling fine. I believe the issue has got to do with the nesting.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, It would be great if you could specify exactly what your issue is. Please do read this before posting questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .  Please update the question with some more information.

Comment: You need to show more details. What is the signature of `updateDetails()` function? What is the type of `app.extension.applicationId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your `app.extension.applicationId` is considered as an `Extension`.

When I see the response you get from your service, I assume that `interface Application` is wrong. I think you wanted to write this:

```
export interface Application {
    id: number;
    parentId: string;
    parentApplication: string;
    extension: Extension; // <- this
}
```

You also forgot the quotes around `updateDetails` in your html code:

```
<button (click)="updateDetails(app.id, app.extension.applicationId)">
      click this button
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much. That solved the issue for me.